# Unable to source file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a scenario where a tomcat user-defined configuration is stored in a file called `tomcat.env`.

In `catalina.sh` we are sourcing the values as below:

```
. "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
```

But as the configuration is present in a different file I tried adding:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f ./envvars/tomcat.env ]; then
   . ./envvars/tomcat.env
fi
```

But the values from the `tomcat.env` file do not get sourced into the shell running the `catalina.sh` script. So the custom configurations are not getting set.

Any idea why this is happening ? or is my understanding of source not right ?

folder structure

```
--bin (contains)
-------- catalina.sh
-------- setenv.sh
-------- envvars (contains)
-------------------- tomcat.env
```

the script is executed from a interactive parent script which inturn invokes catalina.sh and within catalina.sh setenv.sh is sourced which internally sources tomcat.env.

Comment: Does your script enter the `if` block? Add an `echo` statement inside the `if` to be sure. Is the `if` block in `catalina.sh`? Where is that script being run from? Is it in the same directory as the `envvars` directory? Please [edit] and add more details.

Comment: You refer to the file using relative path. Is the current directory set properly?

Comment: @terdon have check the code with echo statements it works, have also updated the question with other details.

Comment: Hang on, what script is supposed to have the variables sourced? You seem to be running `script1 -> catalina.sh -> source tomcat.env`, is that correct? If so, are you expecting `catalina.sh` to have access to the variables or `script1`?

Comment: Are the `catalina.sh` and `setenv.sh` files very long or confidential? Can you post them on some pastebin site and link them here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either execute `catalina.sh` from a directory where `./envvars/tomcat.env` exists as a relative path.  I think that would mean that you have to `cd` to `$CATALINA_BASE/bin` before executing `catalina.sh` in your above example. But that is probably not what you want.

Alternatively edit the `setenv.sh` script to source the `tomcat.env` file by its full path:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/envvars/tomcat.env" ]; then
   . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/envvars/tomcat.env"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of your meaning here:

> But the values from the tomcat.env file do not get sourced into the shell running the catalina.sh script.

But if you are expecting that the parent *interactive shell* from which you are executing `catalina.sh` will have the variable sourced into that *parent* shell, then I would venture to guess that yes, your "understanding of source not right".

When you execute a shell script like `catalina.sh`, and within `catalina.sh` you source another file, the variables (etc.) set within that sourced file will affect the environment  within the `catalina.sh` script, but this won't affect the environment of the parent shell from which you've executed `catalina.sh`.

If you need those values to affect the parent shell, you'll need to either:

1. **Source** `catalina.sh` rather than execute it, or
2. **Source** `setenv.sh`/`tomcat.env` directly from your interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [Lucas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273371/133107) (which contains the most probable explanation for your troubles) you can use the following (assuming the script is executed with bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

CURDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

if [ -f ${CURDIR}/envvars/tomcat.env ]; then
   . ${CURDIR}/envvars/tomcat.env
fi
```